# Git workflow for monitoring changes in certain files in a folder

Tags: git

Suppose I have a folder `data/` with some txt files I want to monitor for changes. I want to run a script and find out what has changed since last commit.

Here is the workflow I have in mind:

1. Make changes: add, modify or remove files
2. Stage all the files `git add data/`
3. List all the changes `git diff --name-only --staged`

This should account for three cases:

1. New file added should be listed
2. Modified files should be listed.
3. Deleted files should not be listed.

I need a command to specifically tell me which file since last commited was deleted. So that I can do some stuff in my script before doing a `git rm deleted_file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use `--diff-filter` to list deleted files only including renaming files. But I think your `git diff` will also include the deleted files.

```
git diff --name-only --staged --diff-filter=D
```

> --diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)...[*]]
>
> Select only files that are Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D),
>   Modified (M), Renamed (R), have their type (i.e. regular file,
>   symlink, submodule, ...) changed (T), are Unmerged (U), are Unknown
>   (X), or have had their pairing Broken (B). Any combination of the
>   filter characters (including none) can be used. When * (All-or-none)
>   is added to the combination, all paths are selected if there is any
>   file that matches other criteria in the comparison; if there is no
>   file that matches other criteria, nothing is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the repository gitk [Link](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitk).It displays changes in a repo or a selected set of commits.

It supports a few options applicable to the git diff-* commands to control how the changes each commit introduces are shown.